# Does adding school or work account threatens my privacy and security?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, security, privacy, office-365

If I add a work account (Office 365) on my phone, will my business administrator without my approval

1. Be able to know my contacts.
2. Be able to read my SMSs. (sent or received)
3. Be able to to install and uninstall apps
4. Be able format my phone.

---

Basic Info:
 - Lumia 640XL
 - Windows 10 Mobile

Comment: i dunno if it answers your query, but once visit this page and see.  http://www.windowscentral.com/two-step-verification-what-it-and-why-you-want-it

Comment: Sorry but this has nothing to do with my question. Thanks for your help.